# Apache convert %20 to \xa9 instead of {space}

Tags: apache-2.2, url, encoding

When I'm trying to access an url like image%20xyz.jpg, I got a 404 error.

When I look into the logs, Apache converts the %20 into \xa9 (and every url encoded characters are transformed to their \xXY values instead of the correct chars (space in that case).

I tried [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) but this doesn't work.

Which Apache directive should I put in my VirtualHost or .htaccess to make something like

```
/img/cms/MISC/Certifi%C3%A9%20AB.jpg
```

Become :

```
/img/cms/MISC/Certifié AB.jpg
```

And not :

```
/img/cms/MISC/Certifi\xc3\xa9 AB.jpg
```

Here's my Apache configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        Redirect / http://www.mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/mywebsite.com/www/"
        ServerName www.mywebsite.com

        <Directory "/home/mywebsite.com/www/">
                Options Includes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com.error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com.access.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And my .htaccess (generated from Prestashop):

```
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# WARNING: PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE MANUALLY. IF NECESSARY, ADD YOUR SPECIFIC CONFIGURATION WITH THE HTACCESS GENERATOR IN BACK OFFICE
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

SetEnv PHP_VER 5
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /category.php?id_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /supplier.php?id_supplier=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms_category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /category.php?id_category=$2&isolang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/content/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /cms.php?isolang=$1&id_cms=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/content/category/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /cms.php?isolang=$1&id_cms_category=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)__[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /supplier.php?isolang=$1&id_supplier=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]+)_[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /manufacturer.php?isolang=$1&id_manufacturer=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/page-not-found$ /404.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/address$ /address.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/addresses$ /addresses.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/authentication$ /authentication.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/best-sales$ /best-sales.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/cart$ /cart.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/contact-us$ /contact-form.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/discount$ /discount.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/guest-tracking$ /guest-tracking.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/order-history$ /history.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/identity$ /identity.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/manufacturers$ /manufacturer.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/my-account$ /my-account.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/new-products$ /new-products.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/order$ /order.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/order-follow$ /order-follow.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/quick-order$ /order-opc.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/order-slip$ /order-slip.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/password-recovery$ /password.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/prices-drop$ /prices-drop.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/search$ /search.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/sitemap$ /sitemap.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/stores$ /stores.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/supplier$ /supplier.php?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/([^?&]*) /$1?isolang=en [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/page-non-trouvee$ /404.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/adresse$ /address.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/adresses$ /addresses.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/authentification$ /authentication.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/meilleures-ventes$ /best-sales.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/panier$ /cart.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/contactez-nous$ /contact-form.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/bons-de-reduction$ /discount.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/suivi-commande-invite$ /guest-tracking.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/historique-des-commandes$ /history.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/identite$ /identity.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/fabricants$ /manufacturer.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/mon-compte$ /my-account.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/nouveaux-produits$ /new-products.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/commande$ /order.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/details-de-la-commande$ /order-follow.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/commande-rapide$ /order-opc.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/avoirs$ /order-slip.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/mot-de-passe-oublie$ /password.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/promotions$ /prices-drop.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/recherche$ /search.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/plan-du-site$ /sitemap.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/magasins$ /stores.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/fournisseurs$ /supplier.php?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/([^?&]*) /$1?isolang=fr [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/pagina-no-encuentra$ /404.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/direccion$ /address.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/direcciones$ /addresses.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/autenticacion$ /authentication.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/mas-vendidos$ /best-sales.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/carro-de-la-compra$ /cart.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/contactenos$ /contact-form.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/descuento$ /discount.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/estado-pedido$ /guest-tracking.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/historial-de-pedidos$ /history.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/identidad$ /identity.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/fabricantes$ /manufacturer.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/mi-cuenta$ /my-account.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/nuevos-productos$ /new-products.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/carrito$ /order.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/devolucion-de-productos$ /order-follow.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/pedido-rapido$ /order-opc.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/vales$ /order-slip.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/contrasena-olvidado$ /password.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/promocion$ /prices-drop.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/buscar$ /search.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/mapa-del-sitio$ /sitemap.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/tiendas$ /stores.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/proveedores$ /supplier.php?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^es/([^?&]*) /$1?isolang=es [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/seite-nicht-gefunden$ /404.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/adresse$ /address.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/adressen$ /addresses.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
R    ewriteRule ^de/authentifizierung$ /authentication.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/verkaufshits$ /best-sales.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/warenkorb$ /cart.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/kontaktieren-sie-uns$ /contact-form.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/discount$ /discount.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/auftragsverfolgung-gast$ /guest-tracking.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/bestellungsverlauf$ /history.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/kennung$ /identity.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/hersteller$ /manufacturer.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/mein-Konto$ /my-account.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/neue-Produkte$ /new-products.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/bestellung$ /order.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/bestellungsverfolgung$ /order-follow.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/schnell-bestellung$ /order-opc.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/bestellschein$ /order-slip.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/kennwort-wiederherstellung$ /password.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/angebote$ /prices-drop.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/suche$ /search.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/sitemap$ /sitemap.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/shops$ /stores.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/zulieferer$ /supplier.php?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/([^?&]*) /$1?isolang=de [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/pagina-non-trovata$ /404.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/indirizzo$ /address.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/indirizzi$ /addresses.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/autenticazione$ /authentication.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/vendite-migliori$ /best-sales.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/carrello$ /cart.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/contattaci$ /contact-form.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/sconto$ /discount.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/ospite-monitoraggio$ /guest-tracking.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/storico-ordine$ /history.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/identite$ /identity.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/produttori$ /manufacturer.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/il-mio-account$ /my-account.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/nuovi-prodotti$ /new-products.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/ordine$ /order.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/seguito-ordine$ /order-follow.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/ordine-veloce$ /order-opc.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/nota-di-ordine$ /order-slip.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/password-recupero$ /password.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/riduzione-prezzi$ /prices-drop.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/cerca$ /search.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/sitemap$ /sitemap.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/negozi$ /stores.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/fornitore$ /supplier.php?isolang=it [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/([^?&]*) /$1?isolang=it [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apache decode URL by default. What does your configuration file look like?

Comment: I updated my post with more details. I also updated the path to the image from the / url, in order for you to see that the .htaccess doesn't have any action on that urls (from what I saw)

Comment: First off, %20 was converted to space just fine in the log line you pasted.  Secondly, the log is always going to encode anything that isn't printable ASCII in order to foil control character attacks.  Finally, what character set is your system using? The log looks like perfectly fine UTF-8 (where `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` is encoded as C3 A9 in hex).

Comment: Ok good to know. I just tried AddDefaultCharset UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 AND ISO-8859-15, nothing changed :/

Comment: Ok I found the problem (but now I need to fix it and I don't know how). that's the files on my system that are badly encoded, with "Certifi� AB.jpg".

Comment: Ok, I did it with `convmv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 -r . --notest`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to close this thread then, but how can I thank you ? I can upvote your comments but they will be delete then, right ?

Comment: @cx42net Well, the correct fix was to use `convmv` etc etc (I've never heard of it but it sounds really cool, what package did it come from?) so you should answer the question yourself with the command you used to fix the problem and mark that as the correct answer once it allows you to.

Comment: For the time you took to help me, you can answer it and I will accept + upvote your answer :)